# How to call angular controller scope function from directive with parameters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

this is slightly different to the other questions on stack in that, I need to call my controller's functions with parameters that exist exclusively in my directive.

directive (markup):

```
<div do-something="doSomething(x)"></div>
```

directive (js):

```
var directive = function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: '/angular/node-for-detail.html',
        scope: {
            doSomething: '&'
        }
    }
};
```

markup inside directive:

```
<span ng-click="doSomething('im not resolving')"></span>
```

function inside controller:

```
$scope.doSomething = function(myVar) { //myVar is null };
```

So the problem is, inside the directive param.abs resolved fine, but then, inside the called scope function the parameters are null! What am I doing wrong? How can I get the parameter to make it through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide on a standard name for the parameter to the function that will be specified in the markup (in your example, you used `x`). Then you can create a function in the directive's isolate scope that will call the `doSomething()` method like so:

directive link function:

```
$scope.runCallback = function (param) {
    $scope.doSomething({x: param});
}
```

Then just change your markup inside the directive to be:

```
<span ng-click="runCallback('im not resolving')"></span>
```

Now your markup call (`<div do-something="doSomething(x)"></div>`) and the function inside the controller will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace your markup inside directive be like this :

```
<span ng-click="doSomething()('im not resolving')"></span>
```

And directive markup :

```
<div do-something="doSomething"></div>
```